# Conflict reason is not the same as Git CLI

Tags: libgit2

I built the libgit2 example program (lg2) and tried its "merge" subcommand.

After issuing "lg2 merge", I ran "git status" to check the result of the merge.

I found that "lg2 merge" and "git merge" have different results, after running the "lg2 merge" command, some files were determined by Git to no conflict and "modified".

But those same files, after I ran "git merge", were determined to conflict and "both added".

I would like to ask what is the reason for this phenomenon? Thanks.

Versions in use:

- Git 2.33.1
- libgit2 1.3.0